# Does it exactly model the real world scenario?

Tags: jmeter, locust

I have been using Jmeter for long time for load testing. Recently, I came to know that Jmeter cannot mimic exactly the real world scenario which can be done by Locust and other performance tools? Can someone please share their knowledge in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

No load testing tool is going to mimic the real world scenario, unfortunately. All are approximations, some worse, some better.

That said, there is a comparison of JMeter and Locust in http://killera.github.io/test/2013/07/29/Comparison_between_JMeter_and_Locust/

I think the main difference is that JMeter uses threads whereas Locust uses an asynchronous approach. This means that Locust should scale to higher connection counts than JMeter, because there is an inherent limit for the number of parallel threads.

How many parallel requests you are expecting your application to handle in the real-world case? It may very well be the case that JMeter using threads is not a problem for your application.

Comment: I am expecting about 10K parallel requests for my application in the real-world case. Which one should be prefer for such a case? Jmeter or Locust?

Comment: Locust, I would say. And I hope your application is not itself based on threads, as 10K threads may be a bit optimistic. If you have a 32-bit system with 3GB/1GB userspace/kernelspace split and 2MB stack space per thread, 1536 threads is the absolute maximum. However, I guess that a high-memory 64-bit system could support 10K parallel threads.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can be pretty close to real-life user simulation assuming proper configuration, see H[ow to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for recommendations and configuration tips.

The only thing JMeter isn't capable of is executing client-side JavaScript, however it isn't too critical. Besides you can use [Web Driver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) to measure end-user performance in parallel with the main load so real-life user experience could also be covered.